# in SQuirrel SQL - unable to use old or new in oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, new-operator

using Oracle DB 10 and SQuirrel 3.7.1

I need to access inserted-fields

If I write in an Oracle trigger script - `:new.fieldName`,

when running the script - I get an input window that says:

"Please input the parameter values
Value for ' :new' ___________ "

the trigger is compiled with a warning - "EDT violation detected"

when the trigger is executed (using an insert) , there's an error:

" Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'schemeName.triggerName' is invalid and failed re-validation

SQLState:  42000

ErrorCode: 4098

Position: 2172  "

what am I missing ?

trigger script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER schemeName.triggerName
AFTER INSERT ON schemeName.tableName1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    Insert into schemeName.tableName2 (fieldName1, fieldName2) values (:new.fieldName, 'someString');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tool (SQuirrel 3.7.1) understands `:` as if you wanted to enter a substitution variable.

There should be an option which turn that **OFF** (at least temporarily) so that you could create a trigger.

Comment: thanks for the hint. in squirrel plugins -> summary, disable the sqlparam plugin and restart squirrel.

Answer (score 0):

goto plugins -> summary, disable sqlparam-plugin and restart squirrel.